# Problems with _imagingft at Pillow library with mac

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm using Pillow library to create an image composed of different Strings but when I use "ImageFont.truetype("sans-serif.ttf", 16)" this line give me this exception:

```
raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

This exception it appears only when I execute the code in MAC, when I use Windows/Linux the execution goes well. How can I make it work in MAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
brew install freetype
pip uninstall Pillow
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: still valid 6 years later (need to pip3 install --no-cache Pillow however)